# How do I add an item to a list without separating it from the previous one? (Python)

Tags: python

So I'm currently solving a problem. The instructions are:

```
accum("abcd") -> "A-Bb-Ccc-Dddd"
accum("RqaEzty") -> "R-Qq-Aaa-Eeee-Zzzzz-Tttttt-Yyyyyyy"
accum("cwAt") -> "C-Ww-Aaa-Tttt"
```

I've written the following program:

```
def accum(s):
dope = []
i = 0
while i < len(s):
    dope.append(list(s)[i].upper())
    dope.append(list(s)[i].lower() * i) 
    i += 1
dope.pop(1)
return dope
```

But it returns `['A', 'B', 'b', 'C', 'cc', 'D', 'ddd']` instead

So is it another method I should use instead of `.append` or how do I combine the upper case letters with the lower case ones?

Comment: `return '-'.join((c * i).title() for i, c in enumerate(s, 1))` — Something like this should do, and be very pythonic…

Comment: It was hard to answer this properly, because the title does not ask the question that you actually have. You don't want to "add an item to a list" at all, because you are trying to make *a string*. "Without separating it from the previous one" is hard to understand; it seems like you didn't want to have each string as a separate element of the list, but that's what a list *is*. So the real question is how to *join strings together*, which is also something you can [look up with a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+join+strings).

Comment: Thanks! But what's the '1' in the `enumerate` method?

Comment: The `1` is so it starts at 1. Otherwise it’d start at 0.

Comment: `[(v*(k+1)).capitalize() for k, v in enumerate(s)]`

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand what data type you need to return. You are working with lists and want to return a String.
`dope` is a `list` type. In order to convert it to a `str` you can either:

1. use `str(dope)`, but this will keep all the commas and `[]` symbols
2. use `"-".join()` with the correct join pattern (according to your needs)

Answer (score -1):

You create a list, you should convert the list to a string. This can be done in multiple ways. You could use approach:

```
def accum(s):
  dope = []
  dope_str = ''
  i = 0
  while i < len(s):
      dope.append(list(s)[i].upper())
      dope.append(list(s)[i].lower() * i) 
      i += 1
  for i in dope:
    dope_str = dope_str + i  
  dope.pop(1)
  return dope_str
```

The output is:

```
CWwAaaTttt
```

Comment: Thanks! It changed it a little bit and this worked:
`def accum(s):
  dope = []
  dope_str = ''
  i = 0
  while i < len(s):
      dope.append(list(s)[i].upper())
      dope.append(list(s)[i].lower() * i) 
      dope.append('-')
      i += 1
  dope.pop(-1)
  for i in dope:
    dope_str = dope_str + i  
  dope.pop(1)
  return dope_str`

Comment: Great. Happy my answer was useful for you.